# Materialize css modal not working with react component

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I am using materialize and the Modal is not working.

In my index.html I imported the libraries:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/utils.js"></script>
```

In my utils.js I put the initialization code for the modal:

```html
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // the "href" attribute of the modal trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
    $('.modal').modal({
      dismissible: true, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
      opacity: .5, // Opacity of modal background
      inDuration: 300, // Transition in duration
      outDuration: 200, // Transition out duration
      startingTop: '4%', // Starting top style attribute
      endingTop: '10%', // Ending top style attribute
      ready: function(modal, trigger) { // Callback for Modal open. Modal and trigger parameters available.
        alert("Ready");
        console.log(modal, trigger);
      },
      complete: function() { alert('Closed'); } // Callback for Modal close
    });
  })
})(jQuery);
```

In my component I put the modal and the button to trigger it, but is not working:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class WeddingTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div className="container">
      
        <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
        
        <div id="modal1" className="modal">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <h4>Modal Header</h4>
            <p>A bunch of text</p>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <a href="#!" className="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WeddingTest;
```

Am I missing something here? When I click on the button the modal is not opening.

I made a test putting the code in the App.js and worked! I am very confusing here. Maybe there is no compatibility with react component or something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should place initialization of modal plugin inside componentDidMount, because when you try to initialize jquery plugin inside  $(document).ready, there is no  on the page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class WeddingTest extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
     $('.modal').modal({
      dismissible: true, 
      opacity: .5, // Opacity of modal background
      inDuration: 300, // Transition in duration
      outDuration: 200, // Transition out duration
      startingTop: '4%', // Starting top style attribute
      endingTop: '10%', // Ending top style attribute
      ready: function(modal, trigger) { 
        alert("Ready");
        console.log(modal, trigger);
      },
      complete: function() { alert('Closed'); } 
    });
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div className="container">

        <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

        <div id="modal1" className="modal">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <h4>Modal Header</h4>
            <p>A bunch of text</p>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <a href="#!" className="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WeddingTest;
```

Comment: I cannot use this in my component. This error occurs: "./src/components/weddings/WeddingTest.js
[1]   Line 5:  '$' is not defined  no-undef".

Comment: How can I get access to $ jQuery variable in react?

Comment: @GuilhermeGomesCorreia  $ is a global variable, you can access everywhere( or you can try window.$), but you should check, that you include jquery library above react code

Comment: I imported the jquery plugin via CDN in my index.xhtml. Do I have to import the jquery library on the react as well?